# How to render(show rendered) mathematical formula in vscode's `hover` documents of python?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, latex

I'm writing for a python function's documentation on vscode, and find it will be very convenient if
the `hover` showing view of a function's docs can render the formula instead of raw string of stiff latex formula, such as the screen shoot:
[image]

As far as I know, there is a solution on Pycharm, i.e., use "`math::`+formula" in docs, but it seems not work on vscode.

So, is there anyway to show formula in python's doc on vscode? Thanks in advance.